# What is the ideal IDE for Actionscript coding on a Mac?

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, mobile, air, ide

Just bought a new pumped up MacBook AIR (i7,8gb ram) that comes with 10.8 OS X preinstalled.
I code Actionscript, Flex for all targets (including mobile). I have used Flash Builder 4.7 up until now, but I have concerns about Adobe's commitment to it.

I have always had Apple macs because i prefer OS X to Windows always.
If budget is not an issue, what IDE would you suggest?
I would like it to be a complete system that lets you debug and test for multiple platforms (including mobile simulators), and ideally would support more than just the AS3 stuff - like Haxe and Javascript (for the future).

IntelliJ IDEA ? FDT? and what about the new CodeOrchestra including the C.O.L.T (no new compiling needed??!!)?

any input would be welcome

thanx a lot
Saar

Comment: I say FlashDevelop, it's even free, but your question is somewhat off place here.

Comment: thnx Vesper. FlashDevelop is Windows only.

Comment: IntelliJ is the best imo. Still not a valid question for SO, though

Comment: thnx. Should i delete the question? Is there a Stack Exchange place more suited for this type of question?

Comment: Programmers Stack Exchange may be better. Either way though, the entire SE network is for questions and answers, while this question is rather asking for suggestions.